# it is alpha but not known in python 2.7 why?

Tags: python

```
import pyarabic.araby as araby

file=open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\quran.txt', "r")

text=araby.strip_tashkeel

text=araby.strip_tashkeel(file)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    text=araby.strip_tashkeel(file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyarabic\araby.py", line 668, in strip_tashkeel
    elif is_vocalized(text):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyarabic\araby.py", line 473, in is_vocalized
    if word.isalpha():
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

Comment: a `file` is not a `string` - the function expects you to pass a string (e.g.: the text from the file), not a file handle

Comment: i want to applied this function to that file ..how?

Comment: Read the text from the file (e.g.: `file.readline()`) and pass that to the function.

Comment: Read the file. There is [some documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is:

```
import pyarabic.araby as araby

with open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\quran.txt', "r") as quran:
    text = araby.strip_tashkeel(quran.read())
```

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyarabic\araby.py", line 279
    return archar in TASHKEEL
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Comment: Can you supply an example of an input that causes this error?